# Editing files in SSH connections doesn't give full content (Windows 7 to RHEL 6.4)

Tags: linux, windows, redhat, remote, putty

When I log into a RHEL 6.4 server (tried two different servers which are identical, a third one did something different but similar) and try to edit a file using vi or nano, the terminal prints only half the file like is visible in the following screenshots.

**mRemoteNG Example:**
[image: mRemoteNG Example]

**PuTTy Example:**
[image: PuTTy Example]

Is this a bug or a configuration issue? 
Could you please help. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong here?

Comment: `xterm` should be fine. Try bringing the server up to date.

Comment: By up to date you mean updating all packages?

Comment: Yes. This system hasn't been updated in at least three years!

Comment: Actually it's a one year old VM

Comment: Then you used a more than three year old OS release to install it, and still haven't updated it.

Comment: Probably. Related with corporate releases. Can't do much about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a given point in the `.profile` file for a certain user it had the command `stty cols 2000` that mixed up the whole column size configurations.

This caused the different editors to think screen size was bigger and thus giving a weird output.

It would, however, be a lot better to have a resize mechanism that detects the window size and resets everything, but at the version of OS I'm using it's inexistent.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the terminal settings in Putty match up with the environment settings in your shell window on RedHat.  I suspect vi/nano thinks your window is bigger than it actually is, so the missing lines are above what you can see.

Not sure where to find the terminal settings in Putty off the top of my head, but use either 'printenv' or 'echo $TERM' in the shell window to see what RedHat thinks what your terminal is.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion in checking `printenv`, but it doesn't seem that anything is strange... :-/

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your program either encountered something that it considers to be a special character and freaked out.
See if you can change Remote Character set and how your terminal handles drawing characters.

Also, do note that mRemoteNG is not popular and is probably not as well developed and maintained as putty or kitty.

Comment: Hello @user3407434 I added two prntscrns and the first one is mRemoteNG and the second one is with PuTTY.